# SSIS:Moving .csv files from share folder to oledb destination on daily basis and sending email notification

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS i'm working on a critical deadline it would be great if someone could help me on this.
I have a share folder in server location //share/source/files where on daily basis one file will get loaded and on a monthly basis one more file gets loaded both the files are of same extension .csv

Can anyone help me in moving the files Say **A.csv** and **B.csv** to corresponding tables and more important is file name on day1 will be A 2011-09-10.csv  and on day2 in source the file will be    A 2011-09-11.csv..This files has to be moved to table A and file B.csv  has to be moved the corresponding destination table table b ,once after moving the files this file has to be moved to archive folder and also we need to send users that tabl-A got loaded with 1000 rows and succesfull similarly table -b load was sucesfull along with date and time .
Note:Source Files will be automatically updated in the folder everyday at 5am in the morning.

Comment: what do you mean by moving files to table? Do you want to read the file and inset it's content on the table?

Answer (score 2):

First, create a variable that will hold the file path name. 
Secondly, create a script task that checks to see if the file is available.
The script task will be as follows:

```
        public void Main()
    {
        string FileName = String.Format("{0}.csv", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

        if (System.IO.File.Exists("\\Shared\\Path\\" + FileName))
        {
            Dts.Variables["FileName"].Value = FileName;
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }

    }
```

After the script task, create a Data Flow Task.

1. Create a connection in the Connection Manager at the bottom of the page which will point to the flat file. In the Flat File Connection Manager Editor popup, set the File name to a file you'd like to upload (this will be updated dynamically, so its actual value isn't relevant). In the properties of the new Connection, open the Expressions popup. Select ConnectionString property, and set the expression to point to the path and the FileName variable : "\\Shared\\Path\\" +  @[User::FileName].
2. Create a Flat File Source, and use the connection we just created as the Connection for the flat file.
3. Create a destination data flow item, and point it to the database you'd like to insert data into.

From here, create a SQL Server job that runs at the time you'd like it to run. This job should execute the package you have just created.